# Why do I get NaN from Maths.max?

Tags: javascript, split

So I am trying to get the highest number from the following test cases:

```
Test.assertEquals(highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"), "542 -214");
Test.assertEquals(highAndLow("1 -1"), "1 -1");
Test.assertEquals(highAndLow("1 1"), "1 1");
```

So far I have the following:

```
function highAndLow(numbers){
    var numbers;
    var str;
    numbers = numbers.split(' ');
    str = numbers.toString();
    var a = Math.max(str);
    return a;  
}
```

I get `NaN`. I know the .split is working ok. Could someone help me out please?

Comment: Why has my question been marked down? Can anyone tell me please?

Answer (score 5):

[`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) accepts a series of numbers or number as strings ([`Math.max` calls `toNumber` internally](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.max) for each argument). The `number.toString()` is not necessary in your code.

If you want to use `Math.max` on an arbitrary number of arguments, you can use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

```
Math.max.apply(null, numbersArray);
```

or spread the array as arguments using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```
Math.max(...numbersArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.max` expects to be passed multiple arguments, where each argument is a number. You are passing it a string.

You probably want `Math.max.apply(Math, numbers)` which lets you pass an array of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

When you split the string we get an array of strings. We need to make it array of numbers. For this use `map(Number)`. Then use the following.

```
function highAndLow(numbers){
    var numbers;
    var str;
    numbers = numbers.split(' ').map(Number);
    var a = Math.max.apply(Math, numbers);
    return a;  
}
```